# What is the current source for in the Schmitt trigger?

Tags: trigger, source, schmitt-trigger

[image: Red outline]

What is the current source for in the schmitt trigger? I can't understand this. Can't see any resistor either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a misuse of the symbol for a current source. Obviously, it should be a voltage source (which sets the comparison threshold), but whoever made the diagram (engineers, marketing, etc.) was too lazy or stupid to use the correct symbol.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe try this circuit instead: -

[image]

Comment: This answer is not constructive. Even though it shows, that it can be "flawless" just posting a counter-schematic does not answer the question for beginners trying to learn. Please consider adding some explanation or improve Zulu's answer with your correct (referenced) schematic. Thanks. :)

Comment: Your down vote isn't constructive either so I suggest YOU leave a new answer and feel free to post my schematic in your answer and do the freaking explanation yourself. While you are at it maybe you can inform the guy posting the formally accepted answer that it doesn't justify the picture in the question. At least my answer produced a circuit that clearly undermines the inaccurate picture in the question thus giving the OP some belief that his picture is not a true representation of reality. I stand by my answer.